# Editar no muestra los datos en los input y select Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, bootstrap-3

De nuevo por acá, estoy ahora trabado con el editar, estoy enviando al model el formulario con el modelo pero los input no me coge los valores, le tengo puesto el name con el mismo nombre que en el modelo y nada, me he guiado por este ejemplo https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html , el modal que utilizan alli no es el mismo que el que yo utilizo ya que alli se trabaja con los field del formulario. Tambien tengo unos select dinámicos y otros no como los podria mostrar con los valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que se carguen los datos al editar necesariamente tienes que usar las etiquetas de los templates, por ejemplo {{ form.nombre }} entonces django te muestra en los inputs llenos.
Ahora por lo que veo tu creaste a mano los inputs con html, si es este el caso tienes que poner en el campo value el valor del campo, por ejemplo:
value="{{ form.nombre.value }}"
De esta forma cuando se renderice la pagina mostrara los datos en los inputs, saludos.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ya habia resuelto, ahora estoy con un plugins multiselect para editar los permisos logro mostrar los seleccionados pero me los repite cada permiso la cantidad de permisos asignados Ejemplo: usuario 1 tiene 3 permisos en la vista me pone cada permiso seleccionado 3 veces, lo hice con for anidados pero no se como decirle que cuando encuetre el seleccionado se detenga y pase para el proximo